# First UserTypedString is not getting recoganised in keyTyped (keyListener) without EventQueue's invokeLater

Tags: java, multithreading, jcombobox, keylistener

This piece of code works fyn. But if I remove EventQueue.invokeLater() , first key that has been typed is not getting recoganised

```
   public static class ListenerDemo implements KeyListener
    {
    String userString = null;
    private String getUserTypedString(KeyEvent e)
    {
        return ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(final KeyEvent e) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                userString = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();
                System.out.println("User str = " +userString);


            }
        });
    }
```

Input in JCombox : 1 , In keyTyped output is  User str = 1

But, If I dont use EventQueue.invokeLater()

Input in Jcombobox which I type is 1 , but output is userTyped =

Then on typing 2, I get output as  userTyped = 1

If all the events are handled by EDT thread , then is it mandatory to use EventQueue.invokeLater() . Why keyType is getting recoganised late?

Comment: Better than using a `KeyListener`, is adding a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the `JTextField`. That is run after the changes, and also catches changes made by other means than pressing keys.

Comment: Yeah we can use. But i just want to know the reason behind this late updation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I guess:
The value of `JTextField` is updated after the event being fired. So when you read text value in `keyTyped` method without `invokeLater`, you can not see the updated value.
When you type a key, two operations are done in the EDT:

1. fire `keyTyped` event by calling your method `keyTyped(final KeyEvent e)` (where you print the text).
2. update text value.

But if you schedule a `Runnable` with `invokeLater`, Swing adds this action at the end of the EDT queue, so it becomes:

1. fire `keyTyped` event (where you schedule a `Runnable`)
2. update text value
3. print the text when `Runnable` gets called

Comment: Wat event is getting fired..Can u explain a lil more?

Comment: (Without eventQueue's invokeLater)First on typing something..KeyTyped will get fired.It runs in an EDT thread.Then i get the user's input and print it.EventQueue's invoke later is only for not allowing the UI to hang.So it adds it to the end of EDT thread. Yet am confused.

Comment: @divya invokeLater is for executing code in EDT asynchronously.